# discord.py pymongo // pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed // error code 8000

Tags: python, discord.py, pymongo

`cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://dbUser:<12345>@discordlevelsys.ehuwh.mongodb.net/<Discord>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")`

So this is my pymongo code

but it occurs error like **pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed // error code 8000**

how can i solve this problem

Comment: Your username or password is incorrect. Can you connect using the mongo shell?

Comment: @BellyBuster thx i solved it